# Rename the files in a Folder, the file to renamed are in excel sheet

Tags: python

There are some files in a folder which are to be renamed.The corresponding file number are in excel sheet. I want the files to be renamed in the folder. the number is in the excel sheet.

```
 Wear-Num     Actual File Name in folder       To be Renamed to
   0.12      WearAnalysis_29April.csv      0.12-WearAnalysis_29April.csv
   0.32      WearAnalysis_26April.csv      0.32-WearAnalysis_26April.csv
   0.23      WearAnalysis_25April.csv      0.23-WearAnalysis_25April.csv
```

The excel sheet contains the Wear-num.
I am Mechanical Engg. Kindly help how to code this or Please write the code for me if possible.

When i run the Python Script, the script should rename as per the requirement as said above.

Comment: `Please write the code for me` SO is not the right place to ask for it.

Comment: I am Sorry I shouldn't have directly ask someone to write code for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `os` or `shutil` like the following:

```py
import os
import shutil

os.rename('WearAnalysis_29April.csv', '0.12-WearAnalysis_29April.csv')
shutil.move('WearAnalysis_29April.csv', '0.12-WearAnalysis_29April.csv')
```

Comment: Thank you for replying Sir,But there are 20 csv files.How should i rename all once rather than writing one by one in code